# Creating Backup using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

i wanted to make a backup of my database but it quiet not working at all.

```
<?php
ob_start();

$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbname   = "dbmaurhotel";

$command = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump --add-drop-table -host=$hostname
--user=$username ";
if ($password) 
    $command.= "--password=". $password ." "; 
$command.= $dbname;
system($command);

$dump = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dbname . "_" . 
date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".sql"));
flush();
echo $dump;
exit();
?>
```

it downloads an sql file but it doesnt contain anything in my database.someone can help me..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all the `ob_XXX` stuff, use `shell_exec()`, which returns all the output.

```
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbname   = "dbmaurhotel";

$command = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump --add-drop-table -host=$hostname
--user=$username ";
if ($password) 
    $command.= "--password=". $password ." "; 
$command.= $dbname;
$dump = shell_exec($command);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dbname . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".sql"));
echo $dump;
exit();
```

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: i enter this C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump --add-drop-table -host=$hostname
--user=$username  in the cmd it says:

Comment: Usage; mysqldump [OPTION] database [tables]

Comment: You have to replace the `$variables` with the actual values. The command prompt doesn't know anything about PHP variables.

Comment: i dont know much..unfortunately

Comment: And you left out the database name at the end.

Comment: You'd better find someone who knows what they're doing. You can't run a database by running to the Internet every time you get confused.

Comment: mysqldump is not recognized..:(

Comment: I don't understand. It was recognized when you tried it earlier, you just left out the database argument.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `bat/bash script` and a scheduler/cron to execute it. Here's a bat version:

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin
set dt=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
mysqldump --databases DATABASE_NAME--user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --skip-add-drop-table > c:/backups/SOMENAME_%dt%.sql
```

This way you will have a `MySQL dump` as often as you run `CRON` or windows scheduler.

P.S. Change the paths accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As php documentation on [system() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) says (bolding is mine):

> Return Values
>
> Returns the **last line of the command output** on success, and FALSE on
>   failure. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.

As the documentation suggests, use the [passthru() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead. But use the $return_var parameter as well because it can give you heads up if things go south.

However, pls note that a backup process may run for quite a while, therefore it is not really recommended to use php to execute it. It is lot better, if the back ups are executed by the scheduler of the operating system running mysqldump utility itself at regular intervals.